# Regex with 'include' list and 'exclude' list

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, vbscript

I have a sentence (words delimited by spaces).

I then have two lists of phrases (full or partial words i.e. contain no spaces): one is an 'include' list and the other is an 'exclude' list.

A matching sentence will contain all phrases in the 'include' list (overlaps are OK, case insensitive) and none of the phrases in the 'exclude' list.

How to test whether the sentence meets the rules? Thanks.

Example

Sentence = `This yammy Flybe catalog is sticky`

Include list = `cat` `fly` `tic`

Exclude list = `veg` `pot` `yam`

Test fails because, although all the 'include' phrases are in the sentence, one of the 'exclude' phrases (`yam`) does appear. Change the word `yammy` to `yummy` and the test should pass.

P.S. currently using relation division implementation in SQL for this, which seems well optimized when the data is aleady in the SQL database. Now I have a data structure coming from an external source. I suppose I could pass in the delimited strings, split into table rows, etc but I want to investigate other options. So if not regex then what?

Comment: I suggest for the added new question, to open up a separate question (make sure it doesn't look too much like a duplicate) where you explicitly ask for other approaches then the one presented in this thread. It's unlikely that people find new questions added during edits... Your example is excellent, btw, and works with the proposed solution.

Answer (score 5):

While I think this is not a good thing to do with regular expressions, you can consider something along these lines (negative look-forward and positive look-forward, anchored at the beginning) when regular expressions are your technology of choice:

```
^(?=.*include1)(?=.*include2)(?=.*...)(?!.*(?:exclude1|exclude2|...))
```

Make sure to use `Regex.Escape` on the individual sentences before adding them in either the include or the exclude expression. The regex works as follows:

- If `include1` is in the matching string, it succeeds, if not, it fails and
- If `include2` is in the matching string, it succeeds, if not, it fails and
- If `includeX` is in the matching string, it succeeds, if not, it fails and
- If `exclude1` is in the matching string, it fails or
- If `exclude2` is in the matching string, it fails or
- If `excludeX` is in the matching string, it fails.

In other words: all include sentences must be in (in any order), all exclude sentences must be out.

Note: this type of regular expressions, even when compiled, are not very well optimized by the .NET regex engine. If the list of includes/excludes becomes large, the simple concatenation routine can already be very costly. Finally, the alternative (match the individual sentences one by one) is possibly even slower. To find out, measure the performance of either approach.

***Update:*** fixed error in code and added explanation.

Comment: Excellent! This must be applied to each sentence, yes? Any way of extending it to apply to the whole tab delimited string or is this madness? Thanks.

Comment: You can apply it to any string of any length. If you want to apply it to parts of a string individually (where the full set of rules apply to the parts), I suggest to split the string first, and then `foreach` through each element and apply the regex on each (don't worry, the regex will be cached by .NET). It is possible to adjust it such that it works for parts between tabs, but this then becomes a very complex regex which even advanced regex users will find hard to understand.

Comment: I spotted the error but by the time I'd posted an example you'd fixed it, good work! This is the regex I was looking for. I'll remove the 'tabs' requirement to see if anything else language-agnostic turns up

Comment: The regex above is "language agnostic" to the extend that any regex-capable language will understand that regex, provided they support look-around (Perl, PHP, Python, Java).